# Create a core dump when running a program with sudo?

Tags: unix, sudo, debug, core, gdb

Cores apparently are not dumped when the using `sudo` despite `ulimit -c` being set to unlimited. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it can be done using the -s option like:

```
sudo -s "ulimit -c unlimited; ./segfaultProg"
```

However 2 caveats:

1. You may need to set the `suid_dumpable` parameter with `sysctl -w kernel.suid_dumpable=2`
2. You may need to move an old core out of the way. Apparently there are special rules where it may refuse to write a core if the suid bit is set, and there's already a core there.

See the following for details:

http://www.randombugs.com/linux/core-dumps-linux.html

Answer (score 4):

sudo will reset the core dump settings, like it does for a lot of other environment state. You can run the program via a helper that first enables core dumps and then runs the program. Create for example a wrapper `/usr/local/bin/coredump` and then `chmod +x`:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/coredump

#!/bin/sh
ulimit -c unlimited
exec "$@"
```

Then

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/coredump /your/crashing/program
```

Comment: I've discovered that even with ulimit -c set to unlimited that, sudo su to root still will not produce a core.

Comment: Yes, I've already mentioned what sudo will reset the core dump setting. You have to do "ulimit -c unlimited" after the sudo.

Comment: That's what I was saying. Sudoing to root using `sudo su` then setting the core limit to `unlimited` it still would not produce a core. This is no longer an issue after messing with sysctl, but despite suid_dumpable behavior being well documented, for some reason it doesn't seem to be as consistent in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Since sudo [1.9.11](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/commit/f279df5e18023a0569657610513743a6bbdf7301), coredumps are explicitly disabled by default, as per the `man 5 sudoers` manual and [this github comment confirming it](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/issues/173#issuecomment-1223337899). Which means that whatever settings you have for `ulimit -c` in your shell, or anything in `/etc/limits.conf`, `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/etc/login.defs` are completely overridden by sudo: ie.

```
$ ulimit -c
134
$ sudo -u user -- bash -c "ulimit -c"
0
```

I use this line `Defaults rlimit_core=infinity` in /etc/sudoers file (or similar, eg. /etc/sudoers.d/90-coredumpsize) to have sudo do the equivalent of `ulimit -c unlimited` while inside sudo.

```
$ sudo -u user -- bash -c "ulimit -c"
unlimited
```

But still heed the 2 caveats from Catskul's (accepted)answer!